# csv.vim pluging how to deactivate it (without uninstalling it)

Tags: csv, vim

I'm using the [csv.vim](https://github.com/chrisbra/csv.vim#concealing) plugging for handling column separated data with Vim.

I don't found in the documentation who to deactivate it.

Comment: Use the plugin's issue tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a filetype plugin, so simply set a different filetype:

```
:set filetype=text
```